# I am new to react, previously I created react apps but not trying to create a react app but after taking a long time it is giving an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, npm-install, npm-package

Previously used this command;

`npx create-react-app 'project_name'`
-but now this is giving error, used other commands as;

`npx create-react-app@latest 'project_name'`
`npm create-react-app 'project_name'`

node version is: v16.17.0
npm version: 9.1.2

same error, then tried to use uninstall react globally and installed it again and tried
`npx create-react-app 'project_name'`

and having same error again..

```
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/@typescript-eslint%2ftypescript-estree: aborted
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ST\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-11-29T19_03_34_604Z-debug-0.log
```

only packages.json file is created and at failure it is also deleted...

As this command was working fine just a few days ago
`npx create-react-app`

I am new to this framework if there is a mistake kindly help me along..

Comment: If you have trouble with create react app, you can also learn React using [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) till it gets sorted out

Comment: The error says there is a problem with your network connection.  Did you look at the log file noted in the error?  What does it say?

Comment: I have read a few articles about creating a new react project and most of them say that you shouldn't use create-react-app while creating the new app. There are a few reasons. You can use [vite](https://vitejs.dev/guide) for it as LiquiD.S1nn3r said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It clearly states that your error comes from a network connection. It may be caused by a VPN. Anyway, if you are new to React and if I may suggest a better solution for you to start a project... CRA is outdated nowadays. Use Vite. Just run this

```
npm create vite@latest some-react-app-name --template react
```